# Testnet Binance Future : Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action

Tags: python, binance, pyalgotrade

I spent a whole day solving this problem and still have not found any solution. I do not know why I did not see any similar case in Demo testnet.binancefuture. I created four accounts with different Gmails on different servers...

```
    from binance.client import Client
    import pandas as pd
    
    
    API_Key = "<api key>"
    API_Secret = "<api secrete>"
    
    client = Client(API_Key, API_Secret , testnet=True)
    
    print(client.get_server_time())
    print(client.get_exchange_info())
    print(client.get_symbol_info('BTCUSDT'))
    print(client.get_all_tickers())
    
    info = client.get_account()
    print(info)
    df = pd.DataFrame(info["balances"])
    df["free"] = df["free"].astype(float)
    df = df[df["free"] > 0]
    print(df)
    
    client.create_order(symbol = "BTCUSDT", quantity = 0.01, type = "MARKET", side= "SELL")
    
    open_orders = client.get_open_orders(symbol = "BTCUSDT")
    print("open orders BTCUSDT  :",open_orders)
    
    open_order = client.get_open_orders()
    print("open orders :",open_order)
```

but I get this error:

```
    {'serverTime': 1644080280117}
    {'timezone': 'UTC', 'serverTime': 1644080280882, 'rateLimits': [{'rateLimitType': 'REQUEST_WEIGHT', 'interval': 'MINUTE', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 1200}, {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'SECOND', 'intervalNum': 10, 'limit': 50}, {'rateLimitType': 'ORDERS', 'interval': 'DAY', 'intervalNum': 1, 'limit': 160000}], 'exchangeFilters': [], 'symbols': [{'symbol': 'BNBBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BNB', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '10000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.01000000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'BTCBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '1000000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000100', 'maxQty': '900.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '100.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'ETHBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '100000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'LTCBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'LTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '100000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'TRXBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'TRX', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00001000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'XRPBUSD', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BUSD', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00010000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00010000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'BNBUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BNB', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '10000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.01000000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '1000000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000100', 'maxQty': '900.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '100.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '100000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'LTCUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'LTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '100000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'TRXUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'TRX', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00001000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00010000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00010000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BNB', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BTC', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000100', 'maxPrice': '10.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.01000000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.00010000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'ETH', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BTC', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000100', 'maxPrice': '100.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.00010000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'LTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BTC', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000100', 'maxPrice': '100.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.00010000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'TRXBTC', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'TRX', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BTC', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000001', 'maxPrice': '1.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000001'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.00010000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'XRPBTC', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BTC', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000001', 'maxPrice': '1.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000001'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.00010000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'LTCBNB', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'LTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BNB', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00010000', 'maxPrice': '1000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00010000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '9000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.10000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '1000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'TRXBNB', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'TRX', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BNB', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000010', 'maxPrice': '10.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000010'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.10000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}, {'symbol': 'XRPBNB', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'XRP', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'BNB', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00000100', 'maxPrice': '10.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '0.10000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '10000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}]}
    {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BTC', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '1000000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000100', 'maxQty': '900.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000100'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '100.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}
    [{'symbol': 'BNBBUSD', 'price': '408.00000000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCBUSD', 'price': '3289.36000000'}, {'symbol': 'ETHBUSD', 'price': '2707.17000000'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBUSD', 'price': '100.00000000'}, {'symbol': 'TRXBUSD', 'price': '0.06018000'}, {'symbol': 'XRPBUSD', 'price': '0.54320000'}, {'symbol': 'BNBUSDT', 'price': '412.00000000'}, {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '41250.00000000'}, {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'price': '687.50000000'}, {'symbol': 'LTCUSDT', 'price': '106.00000000'}, {'symbol': 'TRXUSDT', 'price': '0.06570000'}, {'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'price': '0.30000000'}, {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'price': '0.00993100'}, {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.30000000'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00287400'}, {'symbol': 'TRXBTC', 'price': '0.00000156'}, {'symbol': 'XRPBTC', 'price': '0.00008135'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBNB', 'price': '0.30570000'}, {'symbol': 'TRXBNB', 'price': '0.00015750'}, {'symbol': 'XRPBNB', 'price': '0.00163800'}]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\test.py", line 18, in <module>
        info = client.get_account()
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1956, in get_account
        return self._get('account', True, data=params)
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
        return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
        return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 315, in _request
        return self._handle_response(self.response)
      File "D:\Tavana\Crypto\Bianance_Bot.v0.1.7\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 324, in _handle_response
        raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
    binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so as error indicates this is more to do not with python library but underlying web api error, via documentation [link](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#11xx-2xxx-request-issues) `code=-2015` ("Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.") now given you are getting some data back and just not for `client.get_all_tickers()` my guess would be permissions issue. to dig into issue will need to understand more from that doc site to better understand why getting error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
after i enabled "Enable Spot & Margin Trading", started to working ✌️

Answer (score 0):

in my case, there was not option **testnet=True** flagged.
Now, it works.

api_key = 'x'
api_secret = 'x'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret , testnet=True)

client.API_URL = 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com'

print('Loaded API DEMO')

Answer (score 0):

Since your client is configured for futures testnet, you have to write:

```
client.futures_create_order()
```

instead of:

```
client.create_order()
```